# How do I break this while loop? [python]

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I'm tying to make it so when you enter a digit value in the while loop, the loop ends and so does the program. However when I type "break" I get an invalid syntax error:(. Sorry for the bad coding, this is my first time.

```
print('Hello, world!')
print('What is your name?')
myName = input()
print('It is nice to met you, '+ myName)
print('The length of your name is:')
print(len(myName))
print('What is your age?')
myAge=input()
if myAge.isdigit():print('You will be ' + str(int(myAge) + 1) + ' in "one" year')
else: print('that is not a number. Lets try again, what is your age?')
C = 0
while (C<=3):
    myAge2=input()
    C+=1
    if myAge2.isdigit():print('You will be ' + str(int(myAge2) + 1) + ' in "one" year')
    break
    else: print('Try again')
```

Comment: Indent `break`after the if - also drop the codeblock after the if and else to a newline

Comment: Please add the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indentation to apply the correct `break`

```py
 if myAge2.isdigit():
    print('You will be ' + str(int(myAge2) + 1) + ' in "one" year')
    break
 else: 
    print('Try again')
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried simplifying the code:

```
print('Hello, world!\nWhat is your name')
myName = input()
print('It is nice to met you, {}.\nThe length of your name is: {}'.format(myName, len(myName)))
print('What is your age?')
myAge=input()
if myAge.isdigit():
  print('You will be ' + str(int(myAge) + 1) + ' in "one" year')
else: 
  print('that is not a number. Lets try again, what is your age?')

myAge2=input()
while myAge2.isdigit():
  print('You will be ' + str(int(myAge2) + 1) + ' in "one" year')
  break
else:  
  print('Try again')
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem with the code indentation, otherwise everything is working perfectly.

```py
print('Hello, world!')
print('What is your name?')
myName = input()
print('It is nice to met you, ' + myName)
print('The length of your name is:')
print(len(myName))
print('What is your age?')
myAge = input()
if myAge.isdigit():
    print('You will be ' + str(int(myAge) + 1) + ' in "one" year')
else:
    print('that is not a number. Lets try again, what is your age?')
C = 0
while (C <= 3):
    myAge2 = input()
    C += 1
    if myAge2.isdigit():
        print('You will be ' + str(int(myAge2) + 1) + ' in "one" year')
        break
    else:
        print('Try again')
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Naczw.png)